# Efficient algorithm for weighted random sampling with replacement

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, algorithm, sampling

I have a constant amount of samples, with each sample having a probability. Now I want to resample from this data source to get the **same amount** of new samples, each having the same probability.

For example:

```
                                          random | 0.03 | 0.78 | 0.45 | 0.70
                                          -------+------+------+------+------
sample | 0000 | 0001 | 0002 | 0003   RNG  sample | 0000 | 0003 | 0002 | 0003
-------+------+------+------+------ ====> -------+------+------+------+------
 prob. | 0.10 | 0.20 | 0.30 | 0.40         prob. | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.25
```

In my case, the probabilities wouldn't be given directly but as weights. However, the probabilities can be directly derived from the weights as the sum of all weights is known (but not constant).

In a MATLAB implementation, I used the [randsample](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/toolbox/stats/randsample.html) function of the Statistics Toolbox to achieve this resampling process:

> `y = randsample(n,k,true,w)` or `y = randsample(population,k,true,w)` returns a weighted sample taken with replacement, using a vector of positive weights `w`, whose length is `n`. The probability that the integer `i` is selected for an entry of `y` is `w(i)/sum(w)`. Usually, `w` is a vector of probabilities. `randsample` does not support weighted sampling without replacement.

```
function [samples probabilities] = resample(samples, probabilities)
    sampleCount = size(samples, 1);
    indices = randsample(1 : samplecount, samplecount, 
                         true, probabilities);
    samples = samples(indices, :);
    probabilities = repmat(1 / sample count, samplecount, 1);
end
```

I now want to port this part of the algorithm to an iPad 2 where it is used to update real-time (~25fps) data where **512 samples** are resampled. Therefore, time-efficiency is crucial, as also other calculations will be performed. Memory does not have to be minimized.

I've looked into [the Alias method](http://prxq.wordpress.com/2006/04/17/the-alias-method/), however it seems that the structure building process is quite tedious and maybe not the most efficient solution.

Are there any other efficient methods available which would satisfy the realtime requirement or is the Alias method the way to go?

Comment: How many of these samples do you need for a single frame? What is the size of the set actually sampled from?

Comment: about 512 samples. Both input and output sets have the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to implement your `resample` in C.

```
typedef int SampleType;
typedef double ProbabilityType;

static ProbabilityType MyRandomFunction(ProbabilityType total)
{
    static boolean_t isRandomReady = 0;
    if ( ! isRandomReady ) {
        srandomdev();
        isRandomReady = 1;
    }

    long randomMax = INT_MAX;
    return (random() % (randomMax + 1)) * (total / randomMax);
}

static void MyResampleFunction(SampleType *samples, ProbabilityType *probabilities, size_t length)
{
    ProbabilityType total = 0;

    // first, replace probabilities with sums
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++ )
        probabilities[i] = total += probabilities[i];

    // create a copy of samples as samples will be modified
    SampleType *sampleCopies = malloc(sizeof(SampleType) * length);
    memcpy(sampleCopies, samples, sizeof(SampleType) * length);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        ProbabilityType probability = MyRandomFunction(total);

        // We could iterate through the probablities array but binary search is more efficient

        // This is a block declaration
        int (^comparator)(const void *, const void *);

        // Blocks are the same a function pointers
        // execept they capture their enclosing scope
        comparator = ^(const void *leftPtr, const void *rightPtr) {

            // leftPtr points to probability
            // rightPtr to an element in probabilities

            ProbabilityType curr, prev;
            size_t idx = ((const ProbabilityType *) rightPtr) - probabilities;
            curr = probabilities[idx];                   // current probablity
            prev = idx > 0 ? probabilities[idx - 1] : 0;   // previous probablity

            if ( curr < probability )
                return 1;
            if ( prev > probability )
                return -1;

            return 0;
        };

        void *found = bsearch_b(&probability,            // the searched value
                                probabilities,           // the searched array
                                length,                  // the length of array
                                sizeof(ProbabilityType), // the size of values
                                comparator);             // the comparator

        size_t idx = ((const ProbabilityType *) found) - probabilities;
        samples[i] = sampleCopies[idx];
    }

    // now, probabilities are all the same
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++ )
        probabilities[i] = 1.0 / length;

    // Now the can dispose of the copies
    free(sampleCopies);
}

static void MyTestFunction()
{
    SampleType samples[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    ProbabilityType probabilities[10] = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4};
    MyResampleFunction(samples, probabilities, 4);
}
```